# SystemEvents.TimeChanged is not in Windows CE 6.0?

Tags: c#, time, windows-ce, systemevent

My C# application will run in both windows 7 and windows CE 6.0,

I need to do some operation while change the time so i used below event in windows 7,

```
SystemEvents.TimeChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_TimeChanged);
```

its perfectly working in windows 7

but this is not working in the windows CE, `SystemEvents` namespace not in the CE.

any one tell how to use this event in windows CE.

Thanks,

Comment: You'll have to P/Invoke a bit, see http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/652128-how-detect-system-time-change-compactframework

Comment: Just override WndProc() in your main form to detect the WM_TIMECHANGE message.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis : yes its works.. thanks, put your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive a `NOTIFICATION_EVENT_TIME_CHANGE` notification if you P/Invoke `CeRunAppAtEvent` - see http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/652128-how-detect-system-time-change-compactframework.

Hans Passant's comment (listening for a `WM_TIMECHANGE` event) could be an even more straightforward approach, although this also requires some P/Invoking in the compact framework.